# Setting the value on the SelectBox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to set a value on the select box like below

```
  <dx-select-box
            [items]="reportingProject"
            id="ReportingProj"
            [text]="reportingProject"
            [readOnly]="true"
            >
```

And the reportingProject is in Component like

```
constructor(private psService: ProjectShipmentService, private pdComp: ProjectDetailsComponent) {
   debugger;
   this.reportingProject = this.pdComp.rProjectNumber;
   this.projectSalesOrder = this.pdComp.rSalesOrder;
```

Even though the reportingProject  has data it doesnt show up in the page and the selectbox looks always empty

Comment: Is **dx-select-box** custom made input? Or is that a package component?

Comment: @Arcteezy It is from https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/SelectBox/Overview/Angular/Light/

Comment: Did you miss the closing tag i.e. `</dx-select-box>`

Comment: what does your `this.pdComp.rProjectNumber` returns? it should return an array

Comment: @trx `reportingProject` must be a array or array of object

Answer (score 3):

you can try like this

```js
<dx-select-box id="myId" [items]="reportingProject" placeholder="my placeholder" [searchEnabled]="true" [(value)]="valueData" displayExpr="text" valueExpr="value" (onValueChanged)="onValueChange($event)">
</dx-select-box>

// items: must be a array or array of object 
// displayExpr: key of array of object which you would like to show on your selectbox
// valueExpr: value of your selectbox
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Example](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/SelectBox/Overview/Angular/Light/) of devexpress:

```
<dx-select-box
    [items]="simpleProducts"
    placeholder="Choose Product"
    [showClearButton]="true"
></dx-select-box>
```

where simpleProducts is an array of strings:

```
let simpleProducts: string[] = [
    "HD Video Player",
    "SuperHD Video Player",
    "SuperPlasma 50",
    "SuperLED 50",
    "SuperLED 42",
    "SuperLCD 55",
    "SuperLCD 42",
    "SuperPlasma 65",
    "SuperLCD 70",
    "Projector Plus",
    "Projector PlusHT",
    "ExcelRemote IR",
    "ExcelRemote BT",
    "ExcelRemote IP"
];
```

So you have to **bind items to an array** e.g.:

```
this.reportingProject = [this.pdComp.rProjectNumber];
```